# How to run a specific code on the first start-up of an application?

Tags: java, android, sms, startup

I want to run some code on the first startup of my application, it is to sync the past week's SMS messages to my web application. I'm unsure of how to filter out anything over a week, but this is my code to get all sms messages:

```
Uri allMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(allMessage, null, null, null, null);
while  (c.moveToNext()) {
   String row = c.getString(1);
   //upload the recent 1 week sms messages to the server's database
}
```

I want to run this code only once, so right when it is opened for the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). For example:

```
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
   boolean firstTime = settings.getBoolean("FirstTime", true);
   if (firstTime) {
       // execute your one time code...
       // change the value in the shared preferences:
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
       editor.putBoolean("FirstTime", false);
       editor.commit();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a class that extends `Application`. This will then be run at the launch of your app only.